# Alternate property name while deserializing

Tags: c#, json.net

In reference to this question:

[How can I change property names when serializing with Json.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796618/how-can-i-change-property-names-when-serializing)

Sure, great, but can I have the cake and eat it?

What I'm looking for is an eye pleasing way have an alternate name for a property in such a way that the string may contain either.

Something like:

```
[BetterJsonProperty(PropertyName = "foo_bar")]
public string FooBar { get; set; }
```

Both

```
{
     "FooBar": "yup"
}
```

and

```
{     
      "foo_bar":"uhuh"
}
```

would deserialize as expected.

As solution with no attribute would work or an attribute on the class like:

```
 [AllowCStylePropertyNameAlternatives]
```

Comment: Clearly you want both to work when deserializing (and it may be possible to do using a custom JsonConverter or ContractResolver), but which one should be used while serializing?  You wouldn't want both to be written out in that case, would you?

Comment: Indeed! I'd opt for FooBar but that's a detail. So which one, JsonConverter or ContractResolver and how? No attribute entirely would work as well or just one on the class.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply.  I've added an answer showing how to accomplish this with a `JsonConverter` or, alternatively,  by modifying the Json.Net source code.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is to create a custom [`JsonConverter`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm).  The idea is to have the converter enumerate the JSON property names for objects we are interested in, strip the non-alphanumeric characters from the names and then try to match them up with the actual object properties via reflection.  Here is how it might look in code:

```
public class LaxPropertyNameMatchingConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType.IsClass;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        object instance = objectType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes).Invoke(null);
        PropertyInfo[] props = objectType.GetProperties();

        JObject jo = JObject.Load(reader);
        foreach (JProperty jp in jo.Properties())
        {
            string name = Regex.Replace(jp.Name, "[^A-Za-z0-9]+", "");

            PropertyInfo prop = props.FirstOrDefault(pi => 
                pi.CanWrite && string.Equals(pi.Name, name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

            if (prop != null)
                prop.SetValue(instance, jp.Value.ToObject(prop.PropertyType, serializer));
        }

        return instance;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

To use the custom converter with a particular class, you can decorate that class with a `[JsonConverter]` attribute like this:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(LaxPropertyNameMatchingConverter))]
public class MyClass
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
    public string MyOtherProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Here is a simple demo of the converter in action:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = @"
        [
            { 
                ""my property"" : ""foo"",
                ""my-other-property"" : ""bar"",
            },
            { 
                ""(myProperty)"" : ""baz"",
                ""myOtherProperty"" : ""quux""
            },
            { 
                ""MyProperty"" : ""fizz"",
                ""MY_OTHER_PROPERTY"" : ""bang""
            }
        ]";

        List<MyClass> list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyClass>>(json);

        foreach (MyClass mc in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(mc.MyProperty);
            Console.WriteLine(mc.MyOtherProperty);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
foo
bar
baz
quux
fizz
bang
```

While this solution should do the job in most cases, there is an even simpler solution *if you are OK with the idea of changing the Json.Net source code directly*.  It turns out you can accomplish the same thing by adding just one line of code to the `Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonPropertyCollection` class.  In this class, there is a method called `GetClosestMatchProperty()` which looks like this:

```
public JsonProperty GetClosestMatchProperty(string propertyName)
{
    JsonProperty property = GetProperty(propertyName, StringComparison.Ordinal);
    if (property == null)
        property = GetProperty(propertyName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    return property;
}
```

At the point where this method is called by the deserializer, the `JsonPropertyCollection` contains all the properties from the class being deserialized, and the `propertyName` parameter contains the name of the JSON property name being matched.  As you can see, the method first tries an exact name match, then it tries a case-insensitive match.  So we already have a many-to-one mapping being done between the JSON and class property names.

If you modify this method to strip out all non-alphanumeric characters from the property name prior to matching it, then you can get the behavior you desire, without any special converters or attributes needed.  Here is the modified code:

```
public JsonProperty GetClosestMatchProperty(string propertyName)
{
    propertyName = Regex.Replace(propertyName, "[^A-Za-z0-9]+", "");
    JsonProperty property = GetProperty(propertyName, StringComparison.Ordinal);
    if (property == null)
        property = GetProperty(propertyName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    return property;
}
```

Of course, modifying the source code has its problems as well, but I figured it was worth a mention.

Comment: Love the answer. Having some inner resistance to changing the base code, since I can see how someone does this, says nothing to the team, and somewhere down the track, when someone expects one behavior and gets a different one, the chaos begins :)

Comment: I know this is old, but is something like this possible with System.Text.Json in .net7/8?

Answer (score 9):

Another way of accomplishing this is intercepting the serialization/deserialization process early, by doing some overrides the `JsonReader` and `JsonWriter`

```
public class CustomJsonWriter : JsonTextWriter
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _backwardMappings;

    public CustomJsonWriter(TextWriter writer, Dictionary<string, string> backwardMappings)
        : base(writer)
    {
        _backwardMappings = backwardMappings;
    }

    public override void WritePropertyName(string name)
    {
        base.WritePropertyName(_backwardMappings[name]);
    }
}

public class CustomJsonReader : JsonTextReader
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _forwardMappings;


    public CustomJsonReader(TextReader reader, Dictionary<string, string> forwardMappings )
        : base(reader)
    {
        _forwardMappings = forwardMappings;
    }

    public override object Value
    {
        get
        {
            if (TokenType != JsonToken.PropertyName)
                return base.Value;

            return _forwardMappings[base.Value.ToString()];
        }
    }
}
```

After doing this, you can serialize by doing

```
var mappings = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"Property1", "Equivalent1"},
    {"Property2", "Equivalent2"},
};
var builder = new StringBuilder();
JsonSerializer.Create().Serialize(new CustomJsonWriter(new StringWriter(builder), mappings), your_object);
```

and deserialize by doing

```
var mappings = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"Equivalent1", "Property1"},
    {"Equivalent2", "Property2"},
};
var txtReader = new CustomJsonReader(new StringReader(jsonString), mappings);
var your_object = JsonSerializer.Create().Deserialize<Your_Type>(txtReader);
```

Comment: I must be missing something, but I can't figure it out. I created a .Net Fiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/POERAH . Whenever I debug the code, the WritePropertyName override, isn't being hit. The Value method for CustomJsonReader is being hit, but throwing the given key was not present in dictionary error.

Comment: I wasn't able to get this solution to work for me, but below is another alternative I ended up going with in case it's helpful for someone else. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15915503/net-newtonsoft-json-deserialize-map-to-a-different-property-name