# Json serialization variable PropertyName

Tags: c#, json

I use c# and Newtonsoft.Json library for serialization and deserialization of json.

I have a class like this

```
public class Animal
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Dog")]
    public Key value {get;set;}
}
```

if i instantiate it as

```
Animal a = new Animal{ Key = "bobby" };
```

and i serialize it i'll have a json like

```
{
    "dog": "bobby"
}
```

can i change the PropertyName of the serialization dynamically? for instance, what if i want to put "Bird" or "Cat" instead of "Dog"?

Comment: Maybe writing a custom JsonConverter for it, but is that even a real scenario? It seems like @dotnetstep's solution would give you the JSON you want and would make more sense than trying to use a Property for something other than what it's really meant to represent.

Comment: You may be interested in this [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19792274/10263).

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Animal
{
    public KeyValuePair<string,string> value {get;set;}
}

Animal a = new Animal { value = new KeyValuePair("dog","boddy")};
```

if you want bird

```
Animal a = new Animal { value = new KeyValuePair("bird","bird1")};
```

Comment: This doesn't produce JSON in the format requested by the OP.  It produces JSON that looks like `{"value":{"Key":"dog","Value":"boddy"}}`.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/P51YnE.  You would need a dictionary rather than a single key/value pair for the desired effect.  See [Serialize a Dictionary](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeDictionary.htm).