# JSON.Net Deserialization of non-generic Root Objects

Tags: c#, json, json.net, riot-games-api

I'm currently working on a project where I make a request to the Riot Games API, parse the JSON, and do some stuff with it. I have the request working, and I know I'm getting valid JSON. My issue is using JSON.Net to deserialize the JSON.

The JSON is of the following structure:

```
{
  "xarcies": {
        "id": 31933985,
        "name": "Farces",
        "profileIconId": 588,
        "revisionDate": 1450249383000,
        "summonerLevel": 30
    }
}
```

I want to load this data into the following class

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
class Summoner
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public long id {get;set;}

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("profileIconId")]
    public int profileIconId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("revisionDate")]
    public long revisionDate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("summonerLevel")]
    public long summonerLevel { get; set; }
}
```

The issue I'm having is that because I'm given a "xarcies" object that contains the information I need, I'm not sure how to go about designing a class that can accept the JSON data. I've seen some examples that use a RootObject class to take the object and that class has a subclass that all the pairs are put into, but I can't seem to get it to work. Every time I run it the attributes for the object end up being NULL.

Comment: Is `"xarcies"` a standard property name, or the name of a specific summoner?

Comment: farces is the name of a specific summoner. The api spits it out this way every time it returns JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deserialize your JSON as a `Dictionary<string, Summoner>`:

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Summoner>>(jsonString);
```

The dictionary will be keyed by the user name, in this case `"xarcies"`.  See [Deserialize a Dictionary](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeDictionary.htm).

Comment: Are you the Redditor that pointed me in this direction as well? Regardless, this is definitely the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I just used [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com) to create the following class (its types look a bit different then yours):

```
public class UserData
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int profileIconId { get; set; }
    public long revisionDate { get; set; }
    public int summonerLevel { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public KeyValuePair<string, UserData> value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Okay. That will help with the structure of the classes themselves. Also did not know about json2csharp. Nifty tool. However, I still have a lingering question. This works for this specific object. However, xarcies is a user. That means that depending on which user I request from the API, the class structure would change. Is there a generic way to go about this?

Comment: @Jatrammel can you please try the above?

Comment: Just tried it.  `value.Key` and `value.Value` both come back as `null`.

Comment: @dbc sorry, just read it on a dirfferent question... maybe `Summoner` works better (not better - it works). but I can't copy-paste that from you, can't I?....

Comment: Json.NET doesn't serialize a single key/value pair as a dictionary, it serializes it like so: `{"value":{"Key":"xarcies","Value":{"id":31933985,"name":"Farces","profileIconId":588,"revisionDate":1450249383000,"summonerLevel":30}}}`.

Comment: So, I've been using multiple sources to troubleshoot the this problem. Someone actually suggested I just deserialize into a dictionary that has a string and summoner for a key-value pair, like so

var summonerContainer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Summoner>>(json);

Comment: @Jatrammel got mine from http://stackoverflow.com/a/27327003/4000926 as I didn't knew that...

Comment: Hmm.  [that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27326960/json-serialization-variable-propertyname/27327003#27327003) looks wrong.