# JsonProperty WebApi request and response models

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I have an API that talks to another API.
The response model looks something like this:

```
public class AddressResponseModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string SaveAs { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string County { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
}
```

So, I need to send this to another API. I don't really want to play around with the response in JavaScript, I would just like to send it as it is to my endpoint and let the server handle its factorization.
So, I tried to do this:

```
public class AddressBindingModel
{
    [Required]
    [JsonProperty("address_1")]
    public string Address1 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("address_2")]
    public string Address2 { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [JsonProperty("city")]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [JsonProperty("county")]
    public string County { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [JsonProperty("postcode")]
    public string PostCode { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [JsonProperty("country")]
    public string Country { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("save_as")]
    public string SaveAs { get; set; }
}
```

but the problem with that is that it expects the json to follow to same property format.
How can I get it to expect my unmodified response model, but output the JSON with the underscores?

To clarify, I will post my model like this:

```
{
    address1: '123',
    address2: 'Some street',
    city: 'London',
    county: 'London',
    country: 'GB',
    saveAs: 'Home'
}
```

and my API will then send this to another API like this:

```
{
    address_1: '123',
    address_2: 'Some street',
    city: 'London',
    county: 'London',
    country: 'GB',
    save_as: 'Home'
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? Where's your API contacting another API client or server?

Comment: Just use different models

Comment: You can use a custom json converter to do that. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19792274/alternate-property-name-while-deserializing. Insted of using ReadJson to do your process, you can use WriteJson to change back the properties names.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the same classes to automatically generate JSON with different property names, without having to write a custom [`JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) for each one, you're going to need to create your own [custom `ContractResolver`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ContractResolver.htm), for instance:

- Json.NET provides [`CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver.htm).
- [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33557737/does-json-net-cache-types-serialization-information) has a prototype `PascalCaseToUnderscoreContractResolver`.

If you have a deterministic way to map all .Net property names to the appropriate property names for a given usage context (post or get-from-api), you can create a contract resolver like one of the above.

If, however, there's no general rule for mapping .Net property names for JSON property names, and each context may require some per-property customization,  you could create your own `ContractResolver` that applies in a specific named context, and your own `System.Attribute` that supplies a JSON context name and property name to use in this context.  I.e.:

```
[System.AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public class JsonConditionalNameAttribute : System.Attribute
{
    readonly string contextName;
    readonly string propertyName;

    public string ContextName { get { return contextName; } }
    public string PropertyName { get { return propertyName; } }

    public JsonConditionalNameAttribute(string contextName, string propertyName)
    {
        this.contextName = contextName;
        this.propertyName = propertyName;
    }
}

public class ConditionalNameContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    readonly string contextName;
    public string ContextName { get { return contextName; } }

    public ConditionalNameContractResolver(string contextName)
        : base()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(contextName))
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(contextName))
            throw new ArgumentException();
        this.contextName = contextName;
    }

    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var jProperty = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        var attrs = jProperty.AttributeProvider.GetAttributes(typeof(JsonConditionalNameAttribute), true)
            .Cast<JsonConditionalNameAttribute>()
            .Where(a => a.ContextName == ContextName)
            .Select(a => a.PropertyName)
            .Distinct()
            .ToList();
        if (attrs.Count == 1)
        {
            jProperty.PropertyName = attrs[0];
        }
        else if (attrs.Count > 1)
        {
            throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Multiple conditional property attributes found for \"{0}\" in in context \"{1}\": \"{2}\"", jProperty, contextName, String.Join(",", attrs)));
        }
        return jProperty;
    }
}
```

Then your binding model would look something like:

```
public static class AddressBindingModelContexts
{
    public const string Post = "post";
    public const string GetFromApi = "getFromApi";
}

public class AddressBindingModel
{
    [JsonConditionalName(AddressBindingModelContexts.GetFromApi, "address_1")]
    [JsonConditionalName(AddressBindingModelContexts.Post, "address1")]
    public string Address1 { get; set; }

    [JsonConditionalName(AddressBindingModelContexts.GetFromApi, "address_2")]
    [JsonConditionalName(AddressBindingModelContexts.Post, "address2")]
    public string Address2 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("city")]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("county")]
    public string County { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("postcode")]
    public string PostCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("country")]
    public string Country { get; set; }

    [JsonConditionalName(AddressBindingModelContexts.GetFromApi, "save_as")]
    [JsonConditionalName(AddressBindingModelContexts.Post, "saveAs")]
    public string SaveAs { get; set; }
}
```

To test:

```
        var jsonFromApi = GetJsonFromApi();

        var postContract = new ConditionalNameContractResolver(AddressBindingModelContexts.Post);
        var getFromApiContract = new ConditionalNameContractResolver(AddressBindingModelContexts.GetFromApi);

        var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AddressBindingModel>(jsonFromApi, new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = getFromApiContract });

        var postJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = postContract });

        Debug.WriteLine(postJson); // Verify the postJson has the necessary properties and data.
```

To change the contract resolver for all results returned from Web API, see [JSON and XML Serialization in ASP.NET Web API: Camel Casing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization#json_camelcasing).  To use a custom contract resolver when returning results from a specific Web Api call, see [Customize Json result in Web API](http://tostring.it/2012/07/18/customize-json-result-in-web-api/).