# Execute function as parameter to decorator on property

Tags: c#, json, json.net, decorator

How can I achieve what I'm trying to do here:

```
public class MyClassName
{
    [JsonProperty(nameof(MyProperty).ToJsonIdentifier())]
    public bool MyProperty{ get; set; }
}
```

I have an extension method that can convert the string name of the property to the format I need. But this is not valid c# syntax. Is there a overload or ability to extend the JsonProperty decorator to allow me to specify a function to calculate the desired json property name.

Update: I have a suspicion that perhaps a lambda function could be passed in?

Update2: Is it possible that this would work?

```
public class MyClassName
{
    [SubClassOfJsonProperty(() => nameof(MyProperty).ToJsonIdentifier())]
    public bool MyProperty{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You need to use customresolver. Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48348469/change-json-property-name-in-output-using-json-net

Comment: doesnt quite match, I only want it for a specific property or 6 on this class, not as a general thing..

Comment: to address the duplicate tag - i'm looking for a more general solution - i need to execute a function to send info to a decorator parameter

Comment: Attributes are compile-time things, you can't change them at runtime. Choose a different approach, see duplicate.

Comment: movenext is interesting, but unrelated i guess

Comment: @codecaster, "you cannot do that" is a valid answer, but i'm pretty sure ive seen lambdas passed in before?

Comment: If your question is _"How to change a JSON property name at runtime"_, which it's currently almost literally, your question is answered by the duplicate. If your question is _"How can I determine an attribute value at runtime"_, the answer is _"You can't"_, of which I'm sure there is another duplicate or two. If you're asking _"Can I use a lambda as an attribute parameter"_, then that too is a duplicate, see [Lambda expression in attribute constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16809294/). All those questions have been asked before, try searching.

Comment: is it possible that something like my lambda thing could work? at least for other decorators?

Comment: @codecaster fair enough - i think my question is the second, sorry for the bad formatting -