# Serialize and Deserialize JSON with different property names for different use cases

Tags: json.net

I have data stored in a database with short field names to save space. When I load these into my .NET Core app, I convert the data to its C# model. Then, when I pass this to the fronted I want to serialize the JSON to have full field names. So instead of "fN", "firstName".

I know I can use `[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "SomeName")]` to change serialization/deserialization. What I'm asking is whether there's a way to specify multiple property names for a single field, ideally with some additional "profile" variable so that when I serialize/deserialize from the DB I use the DB profile, and when sending to the client I use the other profile. This way I can either use the short or long names when convenient.

Thanks!

Comment: You can do this with a custom contract resolver.  See [How to ignore JsonProperty(PropertyName = “someName”) when serializing json?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20622492/10263), which is very similar to your question.

Comment: Here is a demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/nxp1pZ.  I changed the `LongNameContractResolver` from the linked question slightly to add a `CamelCaseNamingStrategy` to fit your use case.

Comment: Another example of a configurable contract resolver that allows for alternative names based on context can be found at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34365216/3744182) to [JsonProperty WebApi request and response models](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34362628/3744182).