# c# load Json into inherited class

Tags: c#, json, class, inheritance

I have a C# classes and I need to parse JSON into it.

The class has a `List<>` from another class.

The class structure is like this.

```c#
public class OrderFund {
  public int OrderID { get; set; }
  public int BrokerID { get; set; }
  public string SettlementMethod { get; set; }
  public List<SettlementSap> SettlementsSap { get; set; }
}

public class SettlementSap {
  public string SapMonetaryAccountNo { get; set; }
  public string SapMonetaryAccountType { get; set; }
  public string SapMonetaryAccountOffice { get; set; }
}
```

My JSON is like this.

```js
{
  "settlementMethod": "SAP",
  "BrokerID": 1,
  "OrderID": 1,
  "Settlements": [
    {
      "SapMonetaryAccountNo": "400245892464",
      "SapMonetaryAccountType": "CA",
      "SapMonetaryAccountOffice": "AR"
    }
  ]
}
```

I load my JSON file like this...

```c#
static OrderFund LoadJson(string file) {
  string dire = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
  using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(dire + "\\" + file)) {
    string json = r.ReadToEnd();
    OrderFund items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OrderFund>(json);
    return items;
  }
}
```

The data load fine into `OrderFun` Class but `OrderFund.SettlementsSap` is null.
How can I load `Settlements` into `SettlementsSap`?

Comment: change `public List<SettlementSap> SettlementsSap { get; set; }` to `public List<SettlementSap> Settlements { get; set; }`

Comment: There is a Miss match between the Json and your class. 
Json say the properties is name Settlements when The class has a properies named SettlementsSap. You can modify your class to accept this by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19792274/alternate-property-name-while-deserializing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alternate property name while deserializing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19792274/alternate-property-name-while-deserializing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you have named the field SettlementsSap but your Json field is called Settlements...

You could rename the field in your class;

```
 public class OrderFund 
    {
        public int OrderID { get; set; }
        public int BrokerID { get; set; }
        public string SettlementMethod { get; set; }
        public List<SettlementSap> Settlements { get; set; }
    }
```

or add a  [JsonProperty("Settlements")] 
 attribute to the field like so;

```
public class OrderFund 
{
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public int BrokerID { get; set; }
    public string SettlementMethod { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Settlements")] 
    public List<SettlementSap> SettlementsSap { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: JsonProperty is yuge

Answer (score 3):

You just use a function of Visual Studio which convert your json into a model class

Goto: **Edit -> Paste special -> Paste JSON as Class**

The model class created by this feature will solve your problem

So, visiblely, you must rename `SettlementsSap` by `Settlements`

```
        public class OrderFund
        {
            public string settlementMethod { get; set; }
            public int BrokerID { get; set; }
            public int OrderID { get; set; }
            public Settlement[] Settlements { get; set; }
        }

        public class Settlement
        {
            public string SapMonetaryAccountNo { get; set; }
            public string SapMonetaryAccountType { get; set; }
            public string SapMonetaryAccountOffice { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: did you copy the last question? ahaha

Comment: @MarcoSalerno You means ?

Comment: I saw a question with the same solution posted by another user which you copypasted like some mins ago, (you answered differently in that question)

Comment: @MarcoSalerno haha. I answer the question and learn the others better answers   at the same time :)

Comment: yeah np we are all here to get better and help! :P

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the naming. In the JSON, the name is `Settlements`. But in the class definition of `OrderFund` it is named as `SettlementsSap`