# Property mapping in RestSharp for JSON doesn't work

Tags: .net, json, serialization, restsharp

I have such code:

```
using System;
using RestSharp.Serializers;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var obj = new Order();
        obj.Test = 42;
        var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        var json = serializer.Serialize(obj);
        Console.WriteLine(json);    
    }
}

public class Order
{
    [SerializeAs(Name = "object")]
    public string Object
    {
        get { return "Order"; }
    }

    [SerializeAs(Name = "TestName")]
    public int Test
    {
        get;set;
    }           
}
```

Based on SerializeAs attribute, RestSharp should use names from attribute, not the property name. But it just ignores it. Output for this code is:

```
{
  "Object": "Order",
  "Test": 42
}
```

Am I missed something or it doesn't work with RestSharp?

The same code snippet in DotNetFiddle - http://dotnetfiddle.net/ffaXUY

Comment: Does this even compile? `Object` is a reserved keyword

Comment: We can use class names as Property names. It's ok. But if I would use `object`, then it won't compile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this resource](https://github.com/adamfisher/RestSharp.Serializers.Newtonsoft.Json):

> RestSharp has decided to bring back Newtonsoft.JSON support in v107.0.

So, if you are using a RestSharp 107+, you can safely use `JsonPropertyAttribute` attribute to specify property mapping. This is especially useful when dealing with APIs using another naming convention (e.g. snake case).

[Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15915503/net-newtonsoft-json-deserialize-map-to-a-different-property-name).

Comment: hm, yeah. that's interesting. I'll accept this answer as it's more up to date information. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Well, RestSharp uses SimpleJson, that hasn't any reference to SerializeAs and it also hasn't own mechanism for it.
I found a pull request - https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/pull/331 , but it was closed because of SimpleJson.

In default implementation of `IJsonSerializerStrategy` - `PocoJsonSerializerStrategy` there is some initial logic to do property name replacing, but it doesn't work for now. It has such method - https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/simple-json/blob/master/src/SimpleJson/SimpleJson.cs:

```
protected virtual string MapClrMemberNameToJsonFieldName(string clrPropertyName)
{
    return clrPropertyName;
}
```

So i just replaced SimpleJson to Newtonsoft Json based on the sample from this article - http://blog.patrickmriley.net/2014/02/restsharp-using-jsonnet-serializer.html

Comment: But it doesn't work for deserializing. How can I get such behaviour with response data?

Comment: RestSharp is using Newtonsoft Json.Net for a while. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55915359/2780791).