# Support aliased arguments in get requests for web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, model-binding

### Background

I have a web api project which uses complex types for GET requests, here is an example of a controller method, and its associated complex type

```
[RoutePrefix("api")]
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    [Route("Something")]    
    public IHttpActionResult GetSomething([FromUri]RequestObject request)
    {
        // do something to get "data"
        return Ok(data);
    }
}

// elsewhere
public class RequestObject
{
    [Required]
    public string SomeValue{get;set;}
}
```

This works with a url such as `http://domain.com/api/Something?SomeValue=foo`.

I would like to use alias' for these parameters, for which I will do some complex stuff (once I have this working) but effectively I have defined an attribute `AliasAttribute`.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property,AllowMultiple=true)]
public class AliasAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string ParameterName { get; private set; }
    
    public AliasAttribute(string parameterName)
    {
        this.ParameterName = parameterName;
    }
}
```

Which I would like to adorn onto my request model like so:

```
// elsewhere
public class RequestObject
{
    [Required,Alias("val")]
    public string SomeValue{get;set;}
}
```

Allowing my url to shorten to  `http://domain.com/api/Something?val=foo`. This is a contrived and simplified example, but hopefully demonstrates the background.

### Problem

ModelBinding in web api has become very complex compared to Mvc model binding. I am getting twisted up between `IModelBinder`, `IValueProvider`, `HttpParameterBinding` et al.

I would like an example of where I should hook in to the model binding to allow me to write the value to my model from the querystring - note that I only use this aliasing behaviour when the route uses the `FromUri` attribute (see `MyController.GetSomething` above).

Comment: Geez, lots of hate for this question - I have *absolutely zero idea* what is wrong with this question - AFAICT, its well laid out, and asks a sensible enough question.

Answer (score -1):

Question title:  `Support aliased arguments in get requests for web api`.   I think you are re-inventing a wheel here `AliasAttribute` , and have not given a really good reason *why* you don't want to use community ways of doing this.

I have done something similar with `Newtonsoft.Json` serializer.  But if you want something ootb I'd have to google around.

```
public class RequestObject
{
   [Required]
   [JsonProperty("vla")]
   public string SomeValue{get;set;}
}
```

Example SO that uses it: [.Net NewtonSoft Json Deserialize map to a different property name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15916121/256793)

---

Here is a more agnostic way to do it.

```
[DataContract]
public class RequestObject
{
   [DataMember(Name="val", IsRequired=true)]
   public string SomeValue{get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but its not an answer to the question asked. Im using GET requests, so there is no body to put JSON data in.

Comment: FYI the tooltip over the downvote button says "This answer was not useful". Your help is appreciated (as I commented above) but really, is not useful (in solving my issue). This is still true with the edit. And funnily enough, I have been googling all morning - Just linking to google is borderline rude!