# C# Newtonsoft Json JsonProperty - Constructor 'JsonPropertyAttribute' has 0 parameter(s) but is invoked with 1 argument(s)

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I want to map an object to a different property name when deserializing with Newonsoft Json. I have found the answer both here on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15916121/3850405) and in their [official documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyName.htm) to use `[JsonProperty("name")]` but when I use this code I get the following error:

> Constructor 'JsonPropertyAttribute' has 0 parameter(s) but is invoked
>   with 1 argument(s)

What am I doing wrong? I can build the project but I can't get rid of the red squiggly line.

```
public class Test
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string TestName { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: post code instead of image will help lot

Comment: @PatrickHofman 8.0

Comment: If you're using ReSharper, try clearing its cache, it's on the topmost settings page. Then restart Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify value to `PropertyName` property of `JsonPropertyAttribute` instead

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
```

Comment: Tried this already, I get the error "Cannot resolve symbol 'PropertyName'"

Comment: Might b there is another attribute defined with same name. Try this `[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]`

Comment: Get latest version of `Newtonsoft.Json`, Clean & Rebuild Solution

Comment: I did all of the above but I still have the same error. I can however build the project without a problem but I can't get rid of the red squiggly line

Comment: JsonPropertyAttribute(String) 
Initializes a new instance of the JsonPropertyAttribute class with the specified name.

Comment: @Ogglas Close VS, delete `bin` & `obj` directories within all projects and then start VS, Rebuild solution. Hope that will solves the problem

Comment: @AdnanUmer  and clear out the Resharper cache if integrated within VS.