# Deserializing stored JSON files with old type names into new types

Tags: .net, json, json.net

I have a distributed system which has classes/field names in Norwegian, which I am trying to map to English.  Messages sent via MSMQ are sent as JSON using JSON.Net.  I have messages which contain a serialized object, whose type was originally in Norwegian, is serialized as for example:

```
{ "$type": MyNamespace.Navn }
```

After the code renaming, this same type is now renamed to `Name`, which is the translation for Navn.

Is it possible to configure JSON.Net, that when deserializing that JSON, it will know that although the `$type` was `MyNamespace.Navn`, it now should be deserialized as `MyNamespace.Name` type instead?

(Note: This is related also to this answered question -
 [Mapping multiple property names to the same field in Newtonsoft.JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49253411/mapping-multiple-property-names-to-the-same-field-in-newtonsoft-json/49265269#49265269))

Comment: Can you give a bit more on how you get to serialize to { "$type": MyNamespace.Navn } some sample json with your json settings?

Comment: @ismael. Serialization would have been done when the type still 'existed'. This is handled by the messaging framework, however serialization shouldn't be the issue.The problem is on deserialization, I would need to map it to the new types.  The codebase is aware that the type has changed to "Name". I just need to instruct JSON.Net to use this new type

Answer (score 0):

JSON.Net allows to set custom [SerializationBinder](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeSerializationBinder.htm) to cover such scenario. Here is a sample:

```
public class ReplaceOldTypesBinder : ISerializationBinder
{
    public Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
    {
        //  Put your logic for replacing type here
        if (assemblyName == "ConsoleApplication" && typeName == "ConsoleApplication.OldType")
        {
            return typeof(NewType);
        }

        return Type.GetType(typeName);
    }

    public void BindToName(Type serializedType, out string assemblyName, out string typeName)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Deserialization:

```
var deserializationSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
    SerializationBinder = new ReplaceOldTypesBinder(),
};

var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, deserializationSettings);
```