# Configure Json.Net to ignore property names specified via JsonPropertyAttribute

Tags: c#, json.net

A class in a third-party library I am using has the same JSON property name specified for two properties on a class. E.g. like this:

```
    public class Foo
    {
        [JsonProperty("X")]
        public string X1 { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("X")]
        public string X2 { get; set; }
    }
```

When I try to serialize an instance of that class to JSON, it throws an exception

```
var foo = new Foo { X1 = "a" };
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo); // throws JsonSerializationException
```

> JsonSerializationException: 'A member with the name 'X' already exists
>   on 'Foo'. Use the JsonPropertyAttribute to specify another name.'

How can I configure the json serialization to ignore the property names specified in the `JsonPropery` attribute?

Note that I have no control over the definition of `Foo` and so cannot modify the attributes, etc.

I am not even using one of the conflicting properties, but the exception is still thrown when I specify `NullValueHandling.Ignore` in `JsonSerializerSettings`.

Comment: Why would you want to set two same key on different values for this object?

Comment: @D-Shih I don't. It's a third-party library.

Comment: You can do this with a custom `ContractResolver`.  If you want to ignore all `[JsonProperty]` attributes, see [How to ignore JsonProperty(PropertyName = “someName”) when serializing json?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20622492/10263).  If you want to remap one or more of the `[JsonProperty]` names to something else, see [Json.NET deserialize or serialize json string and map properties to different property names defined at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38111298/10263).

Comment: Thanks @BrianRogers. I guess that means my question is a duplicate.

Comment: Yep, it looks that way.  I'll close it.