# How to Override a Default JsonConverter (specified in an attribute)

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, json.net

I would like the following `Author` type to have a default `JsonConverter`, and be able to override it at runtime.

```cs
[JsonConverter(typeof(BaseJsonConverter))]
public class Author
{
    // The ID of an author entity in the application.
    public int ID { set; get; }

    // The ID of an Author entity in its source.
    public string SourceID { set; set; }
}
```

I used the following code to override the default converter (i.e., `BaseJsonConverter`).

```cs
public class AlternativeConverter : BaseJsonConverter
{ // the serializer implementation is removed for clarity. }

// Deserialize using AlternativeConverter:
var author = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Author>(jsonString, new AlternativeConverter());
```

---

### Question

Using the above call, the `AlternativeConverter` is first constructed; however, then an instance of `BaseJsonConverter` is initialized and used for deserialization. So, the `AlternativeConverter` is never used.

**[Executable example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/l0bgYO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/l0bgYO)**

---

### Use case

The application is to convert different JSON objects, obtained from different sources, to a common C# type. Commonly data comes from a source for that we define the default converter (i.e., `BaseJsonConverter`), and for data coming from other sources, we define different converters per each.

---

### Background

I am aware of methods such as [this one](https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/deserialize-different-json-object-same-class/), and indeed I am using similar method partially. With ref to that article, I need to have different `_propertyMappings` depending on the source of input, because in my application attribute to property mapping is not one-to-one. For instance, I have the following JSON objects:

```
{
   "id":123
}

// and

{
   "id":"456"
}
```

where the first JSON object should be deserialized to:

```cs
author.ID = 123
author.SourceID = null
```

and the second JSON object should be deserialized as:

```cs
author.ID = 0
author.SourceID = "456"
```

Comment: From what I can see, your json keys are the same. the values are only different. So why don't you try to just parse the json string to a `JToken` as the C# object that you need? Unless, I don't quite get your question, it seems like you're making your life difficult.

Comment: Just having a json object is not enough to decide which Json attribute shall be mapped to which property. Hence, it is required to deserialize within the context of the input source, i.e., having different converters for jsons from the different sources.

Comment: Actually it is. JToken is dynamic. You already have an object named `Author`. If you know that the incoming json is of type `Author`, add `[JsonProperty("blabla")]` on top of each variable and parse it as a `JToken` and C# will do the rest. Again, if I'm missing the point, do let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but yes, I guess you're missing the point. If I follow your suggestion (which I am kinda doing now and trying to avoid it), there will be multiple properties with `[JsonProperty("blabal")]`. For instance, both `ID` and `SourceID` will have `[JsonProperty("id")]`, plz see the Json examples.

Comment: Ah now I see, what you're trying to do. based on the type, you're trying to attach the incoming 'id' of the json to one of the properties in Author. If it's an int, to an int. Got it

Comment: No, I guess you misunderstood. I have to deserialize data coming from Google different than those coming from Yahoo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom [`ContractResolver`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_IContractResolver.htm) to override a `[JsonConverter]` attribute programmatically.  To solve your problem you could make a custom resolver like this:

```
public class CustomResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    private Dictionary<Type, JsonConverter> Converters { get; set; }

    public CustomResolver(Dictionary<Type, JsonConverter> converters)
    {
        Converters = converters;
    }

    protected override JsonObjectContract CreateObjectContract(Type objectType)
    {
        JsonObjectContract contract = base.CreateObjectContract(objectType);
        if (Converters.TryGetValue(objectType, out JsonConverter converter))
        {
            contract.Converter = converter;
        }
        return contract;
    }
}
```

Then, when you wanted to use the `AlternativeConverter` in place of the `BaseJsonConverter`, you could use the custom resolver like this:

```
// map the `Author` type to the `AlternativeConverter`
var converters = new Dictionary<Type, JsonConverter>()
{
    { typeof(Author), new AlternativeConverter() }
};

// Create a resolver with the converter mapping and add it to the serializer settings
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new CustomResolver(converters)
};

// Use the settings when deserializing
var author = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Author>(jsonString, settings);
```

Demo Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/cu0igV

---

Of course, if all you're really doing with these converters is remapping properties to different names, you could just use a `ContractResolver` for that in the first place and get rid of the converters altogether.  See *[Json.NET deserialize or serialize json string and map properties to different property names defined at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38111298/10263)* for more information on that approach.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to use different `JsonSerializerSettings` instances for different data sources, with different [Converters](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_Converters.htm) collections. And remove `JsonConverter` attributes from your classes.

Comment: I cannot remove `JsonConvert` attribute because it is essential for (de)serialization of default types.

Comment: Also, I am trying to use something like `Converters`, however, the default converter set via the `JsonConverter` attribute overrides whatever serializer I pass.