# Deserialize JSON string to type with different property names in C#

Tags: c#, json

I have a JSON object that's a string array that looks like this.  It's in a variable called "researchTerms":

```
[{"1":"ifn","2":7,"3":1.81818181818182},{"1":"macrophages","2":5,"3":1.2987012987013},{"1":"n =","2":5,"3":1.2987012987013},{"1":"p <","2":5,"3":1.2987012987013},{"1":"technique","2":5,"3":1.2987012987013},{"1":"cells","2":4,"3":1.03896103896104}]
```

How can I deserialize this in C# using Newtonsoft to an array of ResearchTerms where property "1" is Term, property "2" is Count, and property "3" is Score?:

```
public class ResearchTerm
{
    public string Term { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public long Score { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `[JsonProperty("1")]` etc? I haven't tried that using numerical values, but I suspect it may well just work. That's how you normally control the JSON name.

Comment: Your title results in 266000 Google hits - the first 6 on this site

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.NET NewtonSoft JSON deserialize map to a different property name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15915503/net-newtonsoft-json-deserialize-map-to-a-different-property-name)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change property names when serializing with Json.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796618/how-can-i-change-property-names-when-serializing-with-json-net)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Json.Net you can use the Attribute *JsonProperty*

```
public class ResearchTerm
{
    [JsonProperty("1")]
    public string Term { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("2")]
    public int Count { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("3")]
    public decimal Score { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This works!  I tried searching and didn't find this solution before.  Thanks.

Comment: When using this, it appears to convert the Json properties back to 1, 2, 3 when serialized again to deliver to the client.  Is there a way to convert the values only one way so when reading from my string in the database, it'll turn "1" to Term in my C# code and keep it that way when serialized again?  I'm using this: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResearchTerm[]>(personTask.Result.ResearchKeywords);

Comment: @Andy Yes there is way. But what I know from my past experience is that answering a *"new question"* in comments results in another question. Sorry, I am too lazy to jump into this loop

Comment: @Andy Have a quick squiz at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions