# Deserialize JSON object which have square brackets

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

i would want to deserialize the json object.
But for "Email", there are brackets outside of it.
In Account class, it does not allow to put "[Email]" but only "Email".
Anyone could help on this? thanks.

Class:

```
public class Account
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

The JSON:

```
{
  '[Email]': 'james@example.com',
  'Active': true,
  'CreatedDate': '2013-01-20T00:00:00Z',
}
```

How I deserialize:

```
Account account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Account>(json);

Console.WriteLine(account.Email);
```

Comment: Try adding the attribute `[JsonProperty("[Email]")]` above `Email` property.

Comment: It's worked. Thankyou^^

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.NET NewtonSoft JSON deserialize map to a different property name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15915503/net-newtonsoft-json-deserialize-map-to-a-different-property-name)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can manually change the serialize and deserialize property name by adding the `[JsonProperty]` attribute.

```
[JsonProperty("[Email]")]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

Comment: I was just about to post an answer the same as this... gggrrrr