# Convert json to C# with invalid name

Tags: c#

I am getting Json from third party API, it contain invalid field names like ".issued" and ".expires".
How can I convert the Json to a C# class.

```
{
    "access_token": "fdsfdsfds3243243",
    ".issued": "Thu, 02 Aug 2018 08:14:25 GMT",
    ".expires": "Thu, 16 Aug 2018 08:14:25 GMT"
}
```

Comment: The same as any other, depending on the library you use. Search SO for "JSON.NET mapping"

Comment: Is the missing ',' in line 2 on purpose?

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15915503/net-newtonsoft-json-deserialize-map-to-a-different-property-name) which should help you answer your own question.

Comment: public partial class Root
{
    [JsonProperty("access_token")]
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(".issued")]
    public string Issued { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(".expires")]
    public string Expires { get; set; }
}