# Bind to a POCO model using different property names

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How can I tell Asp.Net Mvc Model Binder to bind some values in the payload to some specific properties in the POCO Model?

For example I have a POCO Model which has 2 properties: **FirstName** and **LastName**, but the JSON object I'm getting has different names, like **first_name_text** and **last_name_text**. I've used a Model Binder to bind **first_name_text** to FirstName property in POCO etc.

I'm using Asp.net MVC 5.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add data annotations over your POCO Model.

Here is better explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15916121/9233618

```
public class TeamScore
{
[JsonProperty("first_name_text ")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
[JsonProperty("last_name_text ")]
public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It's better to flag a question as a duplicate rather than to just link to it in an answer. That is likely the reason for your downvote(s).

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here. Thanks for advice.