# Adapting to content in JSON file used for deserializing with proper coding conventions

Tags: c#, .net, json, string, properties

I am working with a bunch of JSON files that I need to deserialize . A proper I am facing is that some of the Content in the JSON files do not follow proper coding standards , hence when I create the POCO classes I am violating naming conventions

Below is a small example

```
{
    "category": "classified"
}
```

In this case I would have to create a POCO class as

```
public class Category
{
    public string category{ get; set; }
}
```

here I am starting a property name in a simple letter which is bad naming convention in C#.

Anything I can do about that ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change property names when serializing with Json.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796618/how-can-i-change-property-names-when-serializing-with-json-net)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15915503/net-newtonsoft-json-deserialize-map-to-a-different-property-name

Answer (score 2):

Use `JsonProperty` attribute to specify the property name:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
// ...

[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "category")]
public string Category{ get; set; }
```

Comment: @Devss, Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using newer versions of Newtonsoft's serializer it will handle most simple things for you, like this. More complex ones can be handled with an attribute.

```cs
public class Category
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "category")]
    public string DifferentNameCompletely{ get; set; }
}
```