# API IActionResult result

Tags: c#, json, .net, .net-core, json.net

I am creating a .net core API, and i am getting strange response from it.

In the API, internal, I am asking another external API and I am using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject when getting the result from the external API.
I am able to deserialize to my own class, but when I do a request in Postman to my API, I am getting the fields that I am using for the deserialation.

```
    public class InvoiceHistoryResponse
    {
        [JsonProperty("results")]
        public IEnumerable<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
    }

    public class Invoice
    {
        [JsonProperty("properties")]
        public InvoiceProperty InvoiceProperty { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("nodes")]
        public InvoiceFile InvoiceFiles { get; set; }
    }

    public class InvoiceFile
    {
        [JsonProperty("file")]
        public string Pdf { get; set; }
    }

    public class InvoiceProperty
    {
        [JsonProperty("invoicenumber")]
        public string InvoiceNumber { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("totalsum")]
        public decimal InvoiceTotalSum { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("issuedate")]
        public DateTime InvoiceIssueDate { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the code when I deserialise:

```
var invoiceHistoryResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<InvoiceHistoryResponse>(content);
return invoiceHistoryResponse.Invoices;
```

This is the result from Postman:

```
[
    {
        "properties": {
            "invoicenumber": "45293556",
            "totalsum": 1239.55,
            "issuedate": "2000-04-08T00:00:00+02:00"
        },
        "nodes": {
            "file": "https://file.pdf"
        }
    },
    {
        "properties": {
            "invoicenumber": "52095938",
            "totalsum": 989.33,
            "issuedate": "2001-08-18T00:00:00+02:00"
        },
        "nodes": {
            "file": "https://file.pdf"
        }
    },
    {
        "properties": {
            "invoicenumber": "28842180",
            "totalsum": 1504.38,
            "issuedate": "2005-06-06T00:00:00+02:00"
        },
        "nodes": {
            "file": "https://file.pdf"
        }
    }
]
```

But response should looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "InvoiceProperty": {
            "InvoiceNumber": "45293556",
            "InvoiceTotalSum": 1239.55,
            "InvoiceIssueDate": "2000-04-08T00:00:00+02:00"
        },
        "InvoiceFiles": {
            "Pdf": "https://file.pdf"
        }
    },
    {
        "InvoiceProperty": {
            "InvoiceNumber": "52095938",
            "InvoiceTotalSum": 989.33,
            "InvoiceIssueDate": "2001-08-18T00:00:00+02:00"
        },
        "InvoiceFiles": {
            "Pdf": "https://file.pdf"
        }
    },
    {
        "InvoiceProperty": {
            "InvoiceNumber": "28842180",
            "InvoiceTotalSum": 1504.38,
            "InvoiceIssueDate": "2005-06-06T00:00:00+02:00"
        },
        "InvoiceFiles": {
            "Pdf": "https://file.pdf"
        }
    }
]
```

in Controller the endpoint looks like this:

```
[Produces(typeof(IEnumerable<Invoice>))]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllInvoices([FromRoute] string customerId)
{
    var invoices = await _invoiceService.GetCustomerInvoice();
    return Ok(invoices);
}
```

**Any idea why I am getting this strange result?**

Comment: `[JsonProperty("results")]` overrides the property name...

Comment: Instead of `IActionResult` you can use `ActionResult<IEnumerable<Invoice>>` which a) makes it clearer what is actually returned, b) you can omit the Ok wrapper and just do `return invoices;`, and c) you can omit the ProducesAttribute as the return type already specifies this.

Answer (score 0):

JsonProperty is used to change the names of properties when they are serialized to JSON.
So basically when you use `JsonProperty` attribute you response will take the names from `JsonProperty` but while deserialization it identifies the `JsonProperty` names and assigns the right value to the property. Not only postman, all the platform that displays plain response will result into results like this below

```
[
    {
        "properties": {
            "invoicenumber": "45293556",
            "totalsum": 1239.55,
            "issuedate": "2000-04-08T00:00:00+02:00"
        },
        "nodes": {
            "file": "https://file.pdf"
        }
    },
    {
        "properties": {
            "invoicenumber": "52095938",
            "totalsum": 989.33,
            "issuedate": "2001-08-18T00:00:00+02:00"
        },
        "nodes": {
            "file": "https://file.pdf"
        }
    },
    {
        "properties": {
            "invoicenumber": "28842180",
            "totalsum": 1504.38,
            "issuedate": "2005-06-06T00:00:00+02:00"
        },
        "nodes": {
            "file": "https://file.pdf"
        }
    }
]
```

`JsonProperty` use only if you are intended to change the property name while serializing an object.
If you like to modify the property names at runtime, I have posted an answer in other question. check this [Set different property name for JSON at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63682539/c-sharp-set-different-propertyname-between-json-serialization-and-deserializat/63683053#63683053)

Comment: _JsonProperty [is] used only if you are intended to change the property name while serializing an object_ - or of course when deserializing to a different name..

Comment: But the response from the external API has the names that i am specifing in the class, thats why I am putting the [JsonProperty]

Comment: Use contract resolver, you can control serialize and deserialize, see the link in my answer