# C# - Overridden protected method in inheriting class not called

Tags: c#, inheritance, json.net, overriding

This is a question related to inheritance of C# objects, *but in the context of a **protected method** Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver*

I followed the advice of this post on how to use mapping properties for serializing using Newtonsoft library.   [DefaultContractResolver usage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31484563/13632900)

I created classes **AbstractContractResolver, AbstractContractResolverFromFile, CustomClassImplementedContractResolver** *(custom named here for example purpose)*

```
public abstract class AbstractContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver{
            protected Dictionary<string, string> PropertyMappings {get { return this.getPropertyMappings(); }}

            protected override string ResolvePropertyName(string propertyName)
            {
                string resolvedName = null;
                var resolved = this.getPropertyMappings().TryGetValue(propertyName, out resolvedName);
                return (resolved) ? propertyName : base.ResolvePropertyName(propertyName);
            }
}
```

```
public abstract class AbstractContractResolverFromFile : AbstractContractResolver{
            public AbstractContractResolverFromFile(string mapperFileName){
                if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(mapperFileName)){
                    throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("The abstract class {0} uses a mapper file as input to resolve and populate properties.  Please specify a valid mapper file!", this.GetType()));
                }
                this.MapperFileName = mapperFileName;
            }
            protected new virtual string ResolvePropertyName(string propertyName)
            {

                string field = propertyName;
                if(this.PropertyMappings.Any() && this.PropertyMappings.ContainsKey(propertyName)){
                    field = this.PropertyMappings[propertyName];
                }
                else{
                    field = base.ResolvePropertyName(propertyName);
                }
                return field;
            }
```

```
public class CustomClassImplementedContractResolver : AbstractContractResolverFromFile{

            public CustomClassImplementedContractResolver (string mapperFileName) :  base(mapperFileName){

            }

            protected override string ResolvePropertyName(string propertyName)
            {
                return base.ResolvePropertyName(propertyName);
            }
```

The CustomClassImplementedContractResolver inherits AbstractContractResolverFromFile which inherits from the other class and so on.

I use it like this:

```
string mapperfile = "filepath/to/file.json";
CustomClassImplementedContractResolver contractResolver = new CustomClassImplementedContractResolver(mapperfile);
// Custom implementation to store mappings (PropertyName, FieldSource) in a Dictionary<string, string>
await contractResolver.PopulatePropertyMappings();
                
// Reading JSON and deserializing
using(TextReader tr = new StreamReader(jsonfile)){
    string jsoncontent = await tr.ReadToEndAsync();
    try{
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        // Set the ContractResolver
        settings.ContractResolver = contractResolver;
        var item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomClass>(jsoncontent, settings);
```

### Issue -

> Please have a look at my implementations of **the protected function** `ResolvePropertyName` in all these classes above and help me find the issue.

*I **think** I am incorrectly overriding - and `new`ing the method to override further*...

My custom mappings created (from file) cannot be fetched because the incorrect `ResolvePropertyName` is called...

- When *DeserializeObject* executes, the code calls the `ResolvePropertyName` internally, but the current `contractResolver` does not call the overridden method, it actually calls the first base `AbstractContractResolver.ResolvePropertyName`.
  In other words it I put breakpoints in all 4 functions (including `CustomClassImplementedContractResolver.ResolvePropertyName`), but it ***only executes the `AbstractContractResolver` function.***
- Strangely: I use Visual Studio Code and pressing F12 on `base.ResolvePropertyName` navigates correctly (as I expect my implementation to be) from each inherited function until base.

Comment: Do you mean `virtual new string ResolvePropertyName` ? The in the inheriting classes do I keep on doing this in all the sub-classes inheriting from each other?

Comment: No, don't use `new` at all.

Comment: Don't call a class AbstractSomething when it isn't abstract.

Comment: Thank you for spotting that. I will update the base class and make it abstract.   @Geert, may you please give me an example of what you mean?

Comment: Do as mentioned in the answer by Ben. And do a bit or research to find out what `new` actually means.

Comment: Ben mentions `virtual override` , how do I do that on any function at the same time?

Comment: Yes, indeed, override is already virtual, so no need to repeat that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `AbstractContractResolverFromFile` change

```
protected new virtual string ResolvePropertyName
```

to

```
protected override string ResolvePropertyName
```

New-ing something hides the inherited implementation and I would generally recommend avoiding it. It is something to be aware of though as you might come across it in code.

Comment: Sorry Ben, but I do not think I am able to `override` and `virtual` a function at the same time.  `AbstractContractResolver` inherits from the Newtonsoft's `DefaultContractResolver`.

Comment: Yes sorry it should just be `protected override string ResolvePropertyName` I will update my answer

Comment: This solution is still using `virtual override` which is not a possible thing, unless its with more recent up to date C# versions (and Visual Studio) compilers.   Dotnet Core 5 (newest since last week) with C# on VS Code at least does not allow overriding and virtualizing at the same time.

Comment: Sorry I really messed up my answer, that should be it now, just change new virtual to override.

Comment: Thanks @Ben, I tried that before even posting this question.  I have decided to abandon the overrides of the `DefaultContractResolver`, and just created an Extension method that does what I want to do depending on the inheriting type (`FromFile` or `AbstractContractResolver` resolvers).  Works already - `newing` / `virtualizing` behaves strangely (at least in terms of two levels of inheritance that I tried).