# Different Json serialization and deserialization names?

Tags: javascript, c#, serialization, attributes

Is there an attribute to set a Json serialization name and then a deserialization name that is different. I have a `JObject` that has names like `Customer.Age` and I want it to deserialize to the `Age` property and then stay `Age` if serialized again. Anyone know if this is possible with something like a simple attribute or two?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796618/how-can-i-change-property-names-when-serializing-with-json-net

Comment: The `JsonProperty` attribute has an overloaded constructor that takes in a name which is used during serialization instead of the property name itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JsonProperty` did work I just had to set up the class a little differently. I made a constructor with params that had `JsonProperty` on them and then in the body of the constructor I set the property name equal to the param name.

```
public class Customer
{
    public Customer(
        [JsonProperty("Customer.Name")] string name,
        [JsonProperty("Customer.Email")] string email,
        [JsonProperty("Customer.Country")] string country,
        [JsonProperty("Customer.State")] string state,
        [JsonProperty("Customer.City")] string city,
        [JsonProperty("Customer.Phone")] string phone,
        [JsonProperty("Customer.Company")] string company,
        [JsonProperty("Customer.Region")] string region,
        [JsonProperty("Customer.Fax")] string fax,
        [JsonProperty("Customer.Age")] string age,
        [JsonProperty("Customer.Territory")] string territory,
        [JsonProperty("Customer.Occupation")] string occupation
        )
    {
        Name = name;
        Email = email;
        Country = country;
        State = state;
        City = city;
        PhoneNumber = phone;
        Company = company;
        Region = region;
        FaxNumber = FaxNumber;
        Age = age;
        Territory = territory;
        Occupation = occupation;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }   
    public string Country { get; set; } 
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string Region { get; set; }
    public string FaxNumber { get; set; }       
    public string Age { get; set; } 
    public string Territory { get; set; }   
    public string Occupation { get; set; }

}
```

This lets me use `customer.ToObject<Customer>()` on the JObject customer.