# JSON Class with spaces in name

Tags: c#, json

I have been given a JSON definition something along the lines of..

```
{
    "the.data" : {
        "first.name": "Joe",
        "last.name": "Smith"
    }
}
```

and i've made a class in c# to add my data too, such as

```
public class TheData
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public TheData TheData { get; set; }
}
```

Now the web service that i have to send this payload to, is expecting The.Data, and First.Name, as well as Last.Name

How can i 'change' the name definitions? Before transmitting?

Can i somehow override the name?

Comment: Which JSON API are you using? (I suspect you just want `[JsonProperty("first.name")`] etc.)

Comment: if yuo are using Json.Net you cas use `[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]` attribute.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change property names when serializing with Json.net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796618/how-can-i-change-property-names-when-serializing-with-json-net)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this. you can use `JsonPropertyAttribute` to tell `Json.Net` what the property's corresponding `json` field is.

```
public class TheData
{
    [JsonProperty("first.name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("last.name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("the.data")]
    public TheData TheData { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can decorate the values, it will depend on which framework you're using but it'll be something like this:

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Person.Name")]
public string PersonName { get; set; }
```