# How to parse JSON object with another object childen with C#

Tags: c#, arrays, json, getjson

I need the name of property of a property's object :

here is my code:

JSON example:

```
 {
"dados":      [{"codigo_localidade":"1",
"localidade":"Adamantina",
"nome_localidade_pai":"Regi\u00e3o de Governo de Adamantina",
"codigo_variavel":"2",
"variavel":"Cr\u00e9dito Rural Agricultura",
"unidade":"(Em reais de 2015)",
"periodo":"1985\/1989-2011",
"ano":{"2010":"194.140.750"}
}
```

My C# CODE to parse my JSON:

```
  var resultObjects = AllChildren(JObject.Parse(cidadesSON))
                     .First(c => c.Type == JTokenType.Array && c.Path.Contains("dados"))
                     .Children<JObject>();

                    List<Cidade> cidades = new List<Cidade>();
                    Cidade item;
//fetch my array 
                    foreach (JObject result in resultObjects)
                    {
                        item = new Cidade();
                        item.localidade =(string)result["localidade"];
                        item.nome_localidad_pai =    (string)result["nome_localidade_pai"];
                        item.populacao = (string)result["ano"]["2010"];

                        //my problem
                        item.ano = ((JObject)result.["ano"]).Property("2010").Name;

                     cidades.Add(item);

                    }



                    grvCandidatos.DataSource = cidades;
                    grvCandidatos.CssClass = "table table-hover ";
                    grvCandidatos.DataBind();
```

This is the method to get the object

```
private static IEnumerable<JToken> AllChildren(JToken json)
        {
            foreach (var c in json.Children())
            {
                yield return c;
                foreach (var cc in AllChildren(c))
                {
                    yield return cc;
                }
            }
        }
```

If necessary, here is my Model class:

```
public class Cidade
        {
            public string localidade { get; set; }
            public string populacao { get; set; }
            public string nome_localidad_pai { get; set; }
            public string ano { get; set; }

        }
```

If somebody could help i would be very thankful.

(Sorry about my english.)

Comment: The Json you post is not valid http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: What is the type of cidadesSON?

Comment: It is not clear what you want. You can post your question at http://pt.stackoverflow.com/ which is the Portuguese version of StackOverflow. (I know this because I speak Portuguese and I see your variables :) or try to explain better.

Comment: cidadesSON  is a string variable .... The JSON is right because i can access the others properties... I just forgot to close the ']' caracter of 'dados' array..

Comment: In english language it is too much better to find answers ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR**

The problem with your code is that we don't know what's the type of the `ano` property. You could map that property to a `Dictionary<string,object>` and and get the actual `ano` by accessing the Key property of the Dictionary.
See below an example of how you can do this:

Assuming you can use 3rd party libraries in your program, you can pretty much reduce all your code to this by adding [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) into your project:

**"Dado" class**

```
public class Dado
{
    public string localidade { get; set; }
    public string populacao { get; set; }
    public string nome_localidad_pai { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(AnoConverter))]
    public string ano { get; set; }
}
```

**"Root" class**

```
public class RootObject
{
    public List<Dado> dados { get; set; }
}
```

Then, you can create a custom **JsonConverter** to manipulate the deserialization of your json:

```
public class AnoConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        //This deserialize the Ano into a Dictionary,
        //and returns the Key that contains the actual Year you want

        var ano  = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(reader);

        //I'm assuming that there will be always one year here.
        return ano.FirstOrDefault().Key;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Now in your program, just do this to deserialize your json into your strongly typed class:

```
//Just reading the json from a file, nothing new here...
string json = String.Empty;
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("example.json"))
{
    json = r.ReadToEnd();
}

//Deserialize in json into a "RootObject"
var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

This will give you a result like this:
[image]

**Note**
You can do the same process of creating a custom JsonConverter for your `populacao` field but instead of accessing the Key, you access the value. Same logic. I haven't done it on purpose so you can do it yourself and learn :)

Comment: This worked for me, but i released that the name of the Dado class property must be the same of the Json property, do u know how to change this ? There is a problem because `populacao` it is not a valid property name.

Comment: Thank you for answer the question , by the way

Comment: Yes it has to mach. However, you can use the JsonProperty attribute to decorate the property and give it a custom name. See the answer here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796618/how-can-i-change-property-names-when-serializing-with-json-net. I don't get though the populacao problem you said. It looks fine to me..

Answer (score 0):

Use the following method to parse the JSON from NSData

```
   func parseJSON(data: NSData) -> ([String : AnyObject]?, NSError?) {

        var parsingError: NSError? = nil
        let parsedResult: [String : AnyObject]?
        do {

            parsedResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as? [String : AnyObject]
        } catch let error as NSError {

            parsingError = error
            parsedResult = nil
        }
        return (parsedResult, parsingError)
    }
```

If you don't have the JSON in NSData
Convert JSON to NSData using the following function:

```
func jsonToNSData(json: AnyObject) -> NSData?{
    do {
        return try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(json, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)
    } catch let myJSONError {
        print(myJSONError)
    }
    return nil;
}
```