# Create New SubClass and Deserialize

Tags: c#, subclass

I've got a class (bot) and a subclass (player) that I am populating with json from an api.  I want to create a new subclass and serialize it but I'm not sure how to make a new subclass that will actually be a member of the subclass.  How can I add this new subclass?  The console.writeline is working as expected, but once serialized, the expected data is not there.  It's as if the subclass is being added but is not a member of the parent class.

```
public class bot {
    public clan clan { get; set; }
    public war war { get; set; }
    public player player{get;set;}
}

public class player : bot {
    public string tag { get; set; }
    public long discordId { get; set; }
    public attacks[] attacks { get; set; }
    public attacks[] defenses { get; set; }
    public aliases[] aliases { get; set; }
}
```

...

```
    bot bot = new bot();
    bot.clan = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<clan>(json.ToString());

    //assign aliases
    foreach (Memberlist member in bot.clan.memberList) {
        Console.WriteLine(member.tag);
        player a = new player();
        a.tag = member.tag;
    }
```

Comment: First thing to do: learn about .NET naming conventions, and follow them.

Comment: @devhl You can [use the `JsonProperty` attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8796648/424129) to map arbitrary .NET property names onto arbitrary JSON property names.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143016/discussion-on-question-by-devhl-create-new-subclass-and-deserialize).

Answer (score 1):

I changed the player class to a list and then I could use bot.player.add to add the new member to the object.

```
public class bot {
    public List<player> player { get; set; }
}
```

....

```
            bot bot = new bot();
            bot.clan = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<clan>(json.ToString());
            bot.player = new List<player>();

            //assign aliases
             foreach (Memberlist member in bot.clan.memberList) {
               player a = new player();
               a.tag = member.tag;
               bot.player.Add(a);
            }
```