# net core web api json serialization - need fields prefixed with $

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json-serialization

I'm using net core web api and need to return a payload with property name "$skip". I tried using the DataAnnotations:

```
public class ApiResponseMessage
{
    [Display(Name ="$skip", ShortName = "$skip")]
    public int Skip { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "$top", ShortName = "$top")]
    public int Top { get; set; }
}
```

In my Controller I simply use

```
return Json(payload)
```

However, my response payload looks like follow:

```
"ResponseMsg": {
    "Skip": 0,
    "Top": 3
}
```

and I need it to be:

```
"ResponseMsg": {
    "$skip": 0,
    "$top": 3
}
```

What is the best option to address this?
Do I need to write my own ContractResolver or Converter?

Answer (score 17):

starting in .net core 3.0 the framework now uses System.Text.Json. You can decorate a json attribute in your class with

```
[JsonPropertyName("htmlid")]
public string HtmlId { get; set; }
```

See [System.Text.Json](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-the-new-system-text-json-apis/)

Answer (score 6):

ASP.NET Core already uses JSON.NET as its base JavaScriptSerializer.

Here is the dependency.

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc --> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Formatter.Json --> Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch --> Newtonsoft.Json

A sample decoration of the object like this would achieve the goal

```
[JsonObject]
public class ApiResponseMessage
{
    [JsonProperty("$skip")]
    public int Skip { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("$top")]
    public int Top { get; set; }

    ....
}
```

Comment: Thank you for showing that dependency path; that was what enabled to find what version of Newtonsoft.Json is actually in use (10.0.1 for my current setup)

Answer (score 3):

Use `JsonProperty` attribute to set a custom property name:

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "$skip")]
public int Skip { get; set; }
```

Output:

```
{ "$skip": 1 }
```

More info: [How can I change property names when serializing with Json.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796618/how-can-i-change-property-names-when-serializing-with-json-net)