# Is it possible to add fields with invalid characters to a .net AnonymousType?

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, anonymous-types

I'm trying to send a JSON message to facebook that they call a game.achievement but I wanted to create the object using an AnonymousType before Posting.  The problem is one of the fields is "game:points" (with the colon).  As you can see I've used the @ prefix for the *object* field but it doesn't work for the *game:points* field.  It gets underlined in red and won't compile.

```
        var paramsJson = new
            {
                privacy = new { value = "ALL_FRIENDS" },
                @object = new
                {
                    app_id = "my app id",
                    type = "game.achievement",
                    title = "Test",
                    @"game:points" = 100,
                    description = "Test",
                    image = "img.png"
                }
            };
```

I've tried many varieties of @, double quotes etc.  Is it possible or do I need to just use a StringBuilder for this?

Comment: A member-name obviously can´t contain a colon. However you can of course name it `points` or even `@object` (where the `@` just means that you want to use an identifier which has the same name as a reserved keyword (`object` is a built-in .NET-type, as `int`, or `string`).

Comment: What you are asking goes beyond simple serialization. You could use a library like Newtonsoft, create your own class and tell it how to serialize the object: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796618/how-can-i-change-property-names-when-serializing-with-json-net

Comment: @HimBromBeere I wish I could just use a different field name but it has been defined by FB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just use a dictionary?

```
var postData = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    {"game:points", 100}
}
```

Presumably you're going to have to serialize your object to Post it regardless of how it's constructed. Serializing this to JSON would result in the same structure. Alternatively, just do as other's have suggested and create a class for your payload. You can then use Newtonsoft to indicate alternative names for serialization.

```
public class GameAchievement
{
   [JsonProperty("game:points")]
   public int Points {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jesse, a Dictionary<string, object> was all I needed.  I knew resorting to a StringBuilder was a bad idea :)