# How to DeserializeObject with Lower case when use json.net

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a model like this
[image]

when I Deserialize this object, i want to get a  Lower case json  like this 
[image]

what should I do, if you have some ideas,please tell me ,thank you !

Comment: Please do not show your code as a picture. Edit your question to replace it by code cut and pasted from the IDE. Once you have, select it and press Ctrl-K to format it as a code block. And  see [how to ask a question.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Deserialize? Do you mean Serialize *to* JSON? Are you serializing to a string, or is this as part of an API?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change property names when serializing with Json.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796618/how-can-i-change-property-names-when-serializing-with-json-net)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you meant serialise instead of deserialise...

```
[JsonProperty("id")]
```

Decorate the property using the following attribute, example for Id.