# C# Json reading array

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to read the data in a Json, but for some reason I can't find my mistake. This is an example of what I'm looking for.

```
{
   "number": 1,
   "pencil":
   {
      "Array": [
           {
               "color":
               {
                  "red": 0,
                  "green": 0,
                  "blue": 0
               },
               "id": 1234
           },
           {
               "color":
               {
                  "red": 100,
                  "green": 10,
                  "blue": 50
               },
               "id": 1235
           },
       ]
   },
   "something_else": 2
}
```

I tried this line but it keeps doing error.

```
var test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Pencil>>(jsonString);
```

I am trying to get the red, green blue value and the id, but I don't get how.

```
public class Pencil
{
   public List<Color> colors {get; set;}
   public int id;
}

public class Color
{
   public int red;
   public int green;
   public int blue;
}
```

Comment: You need to edit your question to include your `pencil` class and the text of the error you get.

Comment: updated, sorry I forgot

Comment: This json is not valid for this pencil class

Comment: Your array is a list of objects with both Id and Color. Your class list is only of colors

Comment: The *array* is named `Array` in the json file and `colors` in the C# objects, you must use some `JsonPropertyAttribute` to fix that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796618/how-can-i-change-property-names-when-serializing-with-json-net

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, you should have root object:

```
public class Root
{
    public int number {get; set;}
    public Pencil pencil {get; set;}
}
```

Secondly, your property with colors should be named `Array`:

```
public class Pencil
{
   public List<Color> array {get; set;}
   public int id;
}
```

Thirdly, you can't deserialize to `Color`, as in json `pencil` contains `id` property and `color` object. You should have something like wrapper:

```
public class ColorInfo
{
    public int id {get; set;}
    public Color color {get; set;}
}
```

so your `Pencil`:

```
public class Pencil
{
   public int id;
   public List<ColorInfo> array {get; set;} // ColorInfo instead of Color
}
```

Finally, deserialize:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsonString);
```

Comment: You also can use `JsonPropertyAttribute` to specify json element name.

Comment: Thanks I think I get it now! Yeah the root class was probably it!

Comment: @Orace, yes, thanks. But anyway the `Color` array is inside `Pencil` and json has different structure.

Comment: @RomanDoskoch, you wrote: "Secondly, your property with colors should be named Array", this is a breaking change, while it can stay named `colors` if you add a `JsonPropertyAttribute` over it.

Comment: @Orace, why is it breaking change? In code it is much more easy to fix name (you know references). In case if there is a lot of properties with different name in json comparing to `c#` object will you set the attribute for all these not matching properties?

Comment: It's a breaking change because (by definition of a breaking change) you have to modify all the code that refer to this class. The json name "array" is a poor choice for a property, I will prefer to fix the json, but maybe it's not possible. I just want to put forward that your can avoid poor json item name in your code.