# JSON.NET "object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to deserialize a JSON http response, but I keep getting the error "object reference not set to an instance of an object".

I know this is a commonly asked question, but nothing I found about the error has helped me. I think I am missing something very basic.

The JSON response I'm getting looks something like this:

```
{
 "value": [
        {
            "createdDateTime": "2020-03-14T12:25:54Z",
            "id": "W2RQ6DOBCJUXWGR35DLKP7UI6IN",
            "name": "somename",
            "size": 200230,
        },
        {
            "createdDateTime": "2020-03-24T08:25:03Z",
            "id": "Q6DOBCJUXWFIGR35DLWERKP7UI6IN",
            "name": "somename",
            "size": 200230,
        },

        ...
   ]
}
```

I already managed to deserialize properties that only occur once in the response. However, this time I need the properties "id" and "name" back. Here is how I tried that:

```
 public class Value
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Id { get; set; }
            public Value[] Children { get; set; }
        }
        public class RootObject
        {
            public Value[] RespValues { get; set; }
        }
```

```
var objJSON = JObject.Parse(jsonresponse);
var objResponse = objJSON["Response"].ToString();

RootObject categoryTree = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(objResponse);
```

I tried a few different approaches so far, but every single one caused the error. I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change property names when serializing with Json.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796618/how-can-i-change-property-names-when-serializing-with-json-net)

Comment: No, I don't really need to change the property names and I'm not sure if that has something to do with the error I'm getting at all.

Comment: Are you sure? Try putting `[JsonProperty("value")]` on `RespValues`.

Comment: I tried it, but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: You have a comma after the `"size": 200230,` property. It cannot be there. Your `Value` class is missing two properties and this one: `public Value[] Children { get; set; }` doesn't exist. `size` should be of type `long` and `createdDateTime` of type DateTimeOffset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line `var objResponse = objJSON["Response"].ToString();` you try to get "Response" value from your json, but you dont have any field named `"Response"`

Also in your `RootObject` class, you have `RespValue` property, but your json is `"value"` you should make this 2 field have same name.
either you change your class's property to `@value` or your json to `"respValue"`

then, if you want to parse that json, you can use this one

```
var objJSON = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

to access its value, you can use array index or foreach loop from yout `objJSON` variable

Here's my full code based on your question

```
public class Value
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public Value[] Children { get; set; } // will always null
}
public class RootObject
{
    public Value[] @value { get; set; } // Your json's field named value
}

public static void Main()
{
    string jsonexample = @"{""value"": [
                                        {
                                            ""createdDateTime"": ""2020-03-14T12:25:54Z"",
                                            ""id"": ""W2RQ6DOBCJUXWGR35DLKP7UI6IN"",
                                            ""name"": ""somename"",
                                            ""size"": 200230,
                                        },
                                        {
                                            ""createdDateTime"": ""2020-03-24T08:25:03Z"",
                                            ""id"": ""Q6DOBCJUXWFIGR35DLWERKP7UI6IN"",
                                            ""name"": ""somename"",
                                            ""size"": 200230,
                                        }
                                   ]
                                }";
    var objJSON = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonexample);

    Console.WriteLine(objJSON.value[0].Name);

    foreach(var item in objJSON.value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Id);
    }
}
```

Comment: How can we handle the exception in case there is no field named "Response" ?