# Dictionaries and Flurl

Tags: c#, api, dictionary, flurl

I wish to access the "front_default" sprite in the PokeAPI for bulbasaur (https://pokeapi.co/).

I have the following collection initializer:

```
public class PokemonModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Sprites { get; set; }
}
```

And the following code for my WPF MainWindow:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async Task LoadImage(int pokedexNumber = 1)
    {
        PokedexProcess pkdx = new PokedexProcess();
        PokemonModel pkmn = await pkdx.LoadPokedex(pokedexNumber);
        var uriSource = new Uri(Convert.ToString(pkmn.sprites["front_default"]), UriKind.Absolute);
        pokemonImage.Source = new BitmapImage(uriSource);
    }

    private async void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await LoadImage();
    }

    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
}

public class PokedexProcess
{
    public async Task<PokemonModel> LoadPokedex(int number)
    {
        var url = new Url($"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/{ number }");
        PokemonModel pkmn = await url.GetJsonAsync<PokemonModel>();
        return pkmn;

    }
}
```

However, when I try to access the sprite with this I get the following error message:

> Flurl.Http.FlurlParsingException: 'Response could not be deserialized to JSON: GET [https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1'](https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1%27)

Inner Exception

> JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path 'sprites.other', line 1, position 162133.

The only mistake I could think of is trying to access it the wrong way.

To access the specific sprite I need to access https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1 and then sprites->front_default->url of the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the error, because your model expects all values in the `sprites` are keys with values for `Dictionary`. However, according to the payload the `sprites` field contains also objects.

[image]

The serializator can't deserialize `sprites.other` object to the `Dictionary` type.
If you only need to get the `front_default` value from `sprite`, so try to define in your model only the value you need. Something like this.

```
public class PokemonModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public SpritesModel Sprites { get; set; }
}

public class SpritesModel 
{
    public string Front_Default { get; set; }
}
```

If you want to have more C#'s style property name for your `SpritesModel`, for example `FrontDefault`, you can do that with serialization attributes. More details you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796618/how-can-i-change-property-names-when-serializing-with-json-net)

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, this solved my problem. I tried something similar already but used another dictionary instead of a string in the second class.